# Divs with fixed with overlap each other in mobile view - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have done some code like below. This code works properly in desktop view. Basically its a fixed width divs. As soon as goes to mobile view, first and second div overlap. How do i prevent this?? and what exactly is the problem in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row" style='width:100%;border: 1px solid blue; height:500px;'>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style='height:100%;'>
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style='height:100%;'>
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style='height:100%;'>
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class='newrow' style="height:200px; border:1px solid red;">
hii this is me
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are doing some rare thing with the height: 100% and the col-sm-4 because when the col expands to full width in mobile they will overlap because of the full height in the same container. That might be the problem. Remove the 500px height to the row and set it to each col-sm-4

Comment: I wanted to avoid giving height to each div.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `height: 100%` on mobile screens i.e. `@max-width: 768px`. Avoid using inline styles since maintenance would take much time and confusion. Edited your code with standard CSS overriding.

```css
.custom-height {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 500px;
}
.newrow {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .custom-height {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row custom-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="newrow">
    hii this is me
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```